# DQL Query - Right Join

Tags: symfony, dql

I want to count how many times my theme is used in my Blog.

Any blog posts (articles in french) can use one or more theme.

So I have a table (ManyToMany) :

- themes_articles (id_theme,id_article)
  And :
- theme (id_theme,nom_theme)
- articles (blog posts) (id_article, description ...)

In SQL, I do :

```
SELECT T.id,nom_theme,count(A.themes_id) from themes_articles A right join themes T on T.id=A.themes_id group by nom_theme
```

It works, but when I want to use right join in DQL, it's a little bit hard. I switched my two tables for use a left join but I don't know how I can use my relation table here (themes_articles).

I tried something like this :

```
 $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('')
->select(array('T.id', 'nomTheme', 'count(A.themes_id) as nombre'))
->from('themes', 'T')
->leftJoin('themes_articles', 'A', 'WITH', 'T.id= A.themes_id')
->groupBy('nom_theme');
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But it doesn't work.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 93 near 'themes_articles': Error: Class 'themes_articles' is not defined.
```

How can I do to convert my SQL request in DQL request ?

Thank you a lot for any help.

Comment: What does It mean "doesn't work"? Do you retrieve errors?

Comment: Hi. 

Yes, I have this error :
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 93 near 'themes_articles': Error: Class 'themes_articles' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
->leftJoin('themes_articles', 'A', 'WITH', 'T.id= A.themes_id')
```

to this:

```
->leftJoin('YourBundle:themes_articles', 'A', 'WITH', 'T.id= A.themes_id')
```

Comment: Hi, 

Same thing,
 [Semantical Error] line 0, col 93 near 'BlogBundle:themes_articles': Error: Class 'BlogBundle\Entity\themes_articles' is not defined.